# Shape keys and material

Tags: shape-keys

I'm following a tutorial on YouTube, but I got stuck in *Shape Keys*. I made 2 keys: *open* and *closed* to make eyes blink. I clicked *closed* and change the value up to max. Then I added material to change the color to green. I switched back to object mode and decrease the value to 0, but the eyes didn't change from green to white.  How do I get them to change?

This tutorial I'm learning right now is [Blender 2.83 Easy Character Rigging](https://youtu.be/4VEWQ_0NixI)

Comment: I may miss something but you can't change the material with shape keys, what you can probably do though is create a driver on the shape key in order to command a mix shader factor in your material

Answer (score 5):

To visualize Moonboots' comment:

[image]

Either drive some value inside your shader (here factor of MixRGB) with the shape key's value, or use a custom property that drives both. Here I used the easy way of adding a driver by right-clicking source: "Copy as New Driver" and right-clicking destination: "Paste Driver".